# Is Redis' set command an atomic operation?

Tags: redis, locking, distributed-computing

I'm trying to use Redis' `set` command to implement a simplest distributed lock component, but I can't find any exact basis about atomicity through the official document, is Redis' `SET key value [EX seconds] [PX milliseconds] [NX|XX]` command an atomic operation?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes. The core is single threaded, so *nothing* will run until the `SET` has completed; that makes `SET {key} {value} EX {expiry} NX` ideal for simple locking.

Comment: A `SET` will block *all* operations  even on *other* keys in the same database?

Comment: @Matthew **all** operations very briefly block (not really the right word) all other operations; the core is single-threaded, but insanely fast.

Comment: I worry about *my* code that's controlling the Redis ops!  LOL   Why is block not the right word?

Comment: @Matthew because I don't mean "block" it in the usual database sense of one operation taking some kind of locks on specific data (page locks, row locks, etc); there is no locking - there's just a single thread, which means it can only be processing a single thing; that's why ops that need to be atomic should use lua (`EVAL`/`EVALSHA`) or a `MULTI`/`EXEC` batch, or (best option) an inbuilt atomic operation; in the case of the question, `SET` with `EX` and `NX` performs a few different things (checking existence, setting the value, setting the expiry) all in one atomic operation

Comment: Gotcha gotcha.  Although I do think *blocking* is is an appropriate term here.

Comment: The above works only with a single master instance. Refer this doc for some implementing libraries in different languages. https://redis.io/topics/distlock