# Node-redis: transactionally delete multiple keys

Tags: redis, node-redis

I've been trying to transactionally one or several keys using `multi()` as per [stated in the node-redis docs](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#transactions-multiexec), like so:

```
const deleteRedisCacheKeys = async (cacheKeys) => {
  // transactionally delete cache keys
  await redis
    .multi()
    .del(...cacheKeys)
    .exec();

  return true;
};
```

Where `cacheKeys` is an array of one or several strings:

```
const cacheKeys = [
  'cache-key-1',
  'cache-key-2',
  ...
  'cache-key-n',
];
```

However this method will only delete the first iterated item and ignore the rest without aborting the transaction.

I've seen several posts of how to delete an array of keys, but I'd like to do it with a transaction to ensure that they are all getting deleted, or none should.

Is this even possible without some sort of memory killing loop?

Comment: You don't need `multi` in this case, since `del` with multiple keys is atomic.

Comment: So basically since it's atomic it should guarantee that all the keys are deleted or it would fail? `Multi` should only be used for non atomic operations. Seen an acceptable explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259635/is-redis-set-command-an-atomic-operation